# Cannot create table in PHP , no error message shown

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to create a table on PHP but it does not create any table

```
    $Usernaam = YuYu;
    $UserAppartement = $Usernaam . "_Appartement";
    $Usertable = $Usernaam. "_Huizen";
    $immodata = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "password") or die(mysql_error());

    mysql_select_db("immodata", $immodata);


    $sql = "create table $UserAppartement 
    (
                ID int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
                SoortLokatie_ID int(11) NOT NULL,
                Verdieping varchar(15) NOT NULL,
                GasMN   int(15) ,
                ElektriciteitMN int(15) ,
                WaterMN int(15) ,
                EAN_Gas varchar(15) ,
                EAN_Elektriciteit   varchar(15) ,
                Oppervlakte int(3) ,
                Kamers  int(1),
                Tuin    TINYINT(1) ,
                Terras  TINYINT(1) ,
                Living  TINYINT(1),
                Keuken  TINYINT(1) ,
                Balkon  TINYINT(1) ,
                Badkamer    TINYINT(1) ,
                Toilet  TINYINT(1),
                Beschrijving    varchar(1000) default 'Geen beschrijving',
                Status_ID   int(1),
                Zoek_ID varchar(6),
                Huis_ID int(11),
                PRIMARY KEY (ID),
                FOREIGN KEY (Huis_ID) REFERENCES $Usertable(ID);

    )
            ";


    echo "Table has been created ";
    mysql_query($sql, $immodata);
```

The echo at the end works , but the table is not created. I don't receive any kind of error message.

Comment: Use `mysql_error()` to see the error.

Comment: thanks for helping , but it doesn't show any errors

Comment: Pay atention in your `Foreign Key` - check if your table field has the same type, ie, INT (UN)SIGNED must the same in each fields.

Comment: use this `mysql_query($sql, $immodata) or die(mysql_error());`

Comment: Remove the semicolon before last parenthesis

Comment: Your error is `Cannot add foreign key constraint`. :-)

Comment: show your `$Usertable`

Comment: I'm creating a website where people can add appartment that they can rent =D . Thank you very much Ashalynd ! it was the semicolon that caused the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code for solve you problem

```
  <?php
   $con=mysqli_connect("example.com","peter","abc123","my_db");
  // Check connection
  if (mysqli_connect_errno())
   {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
   }

   // Create table
     $sql="CREATE TABLE Persons(FirstName CHAR(30),LastName CHAR(30),Age INT)";

     // Execute query
     if (mysqli_query($con,$sql))
    {
   echo "Table persons created successfully";
    }
   else
    {
     echo "Error creating table: " . mysqli_error($con);
    }
?>
```